# class validator not working with class transformer's type function

Tags: class-validator, class-transformer

```
class Product {
  @Min(0, { message: 'should be positive number' })
  @IsNotEmpty({ message: 'should not be empty' })
  @Type(() => Number)
  price: number;
}
```

*In this case, `price` come from input value, so it should be string at first.

I want to show error message that following cases by class-validator, but only `@IsNotEmpty` not working.

1. If field is empty, show 'should not be empty'
2. If field is not empty && field value is negative, show 'should be positive number'

why `@IsNotEmpty` not working with `@Type` type function?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have mixed up `class-validator` and `class-transformer`'s decorators.

My understanding is that `@Type` is solely used by `class-transformer` to aid in transforming the type of a nested object. That issue aside, I believe the order in which you declare your validators matters. This should work:

```
class Product {
  @IsNotEmpty({ message: 'should not be empty' })
  @Min(0, { message: 'should be positive number' })
  price: number;
}
```